# Function works after second click

Tags: jquery

this is part of my code, and I don't understand why it works after second click. It should work after first click
[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/kngU8/1/)

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
    var mainfunction = function(){
        var $eachblocks = $(".top10_month .periods");
        var $blockhead = $(".block-head__link");
        $blockhead.on("click", function(e){

            var $this = $(this);
            var typelink = $(".block-head__link.active").attr("data-date");
            e.preventDefault();
            $this.parents("ul").find("a").removeClass("active");
            this.className += " active";
            $this.parents(".block-parent").find(".periods").removeClass('active');
            $this.parents(".block-parent").find(".periods[data-period="+typelink+"]").addClass('active');
        });
    };
    mainfunction();
});
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to read the data from the clicked element

```
var typelink = $this.data("date");
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/69fjv/)

When you click the first time, you are reading the data of the active element which is december before the active class is assigned to the currently clicked element

Comment: btw, it should be `$(this).data('date');`

Comment: @ManishMishra thanks.... didn't notice that part

Comment: Btw, `mainfunction` should not take a parameter `e`.

Comment: @OlivierH yes you are right

Comment: +1 for actually explaining _why_ it doesn't work.

Answer (score 1):

You should use current object which is in `$this`, it wll always look for the first `$('.block-head__link.active')` in DOM, you click event won't work first time:

```
var typelink = $this.attr("date"); // $this change here
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/kngU8/3/)

Answer (score 1):

try this

Working fiddle: jsfiddle.net/kngU8/5

```
$blockhead.on("click", function(e){
        var $this = $(this);
        var typelink = $this.attr("data-date"); 
        $this.parents("ul").find("a").removeClass("active");
        this.className += " active";
        $this.parents(".block-parent").find(".periods").removeClass('active');
        $this.parents(".block-parent").find(".periods[data-period="+typelink+"]").addClass('active'); 
        return false;
    });
```

Comment: not working in jsfiddle... please provide your working jsfiddle

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/kngU8/5/

Comment: +1 for providing fiddle. put your fiddle in your answer...

Answer (score 0):

working jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/patelmilanb1/kngU8/6/

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var myfunction = function () {
        $(".block-head__link").on("click", function (e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            var typelink = $(this).data("date");
            $('.block-head__menu').removeClass("active");
            $(this).addClass("active");
            $(".periods").removeClass('active');
            $(".periods[data-period=" + typelink + "]").addClass('active');
        });
    };
    myfunction();
});
```